# How to give background image in CSS?

Tags: css

I am doing project in asp.net. I want to give one background image to my page using CSS.
in the CSS sheet,i have given like `"background-image : 'image.jpg';`" , 
but i am not getting the image in the output page.

Does anyone know how to give background image in CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should just be  `background-image:url('image.jpg');`

[background-image documentation is readily available if you look for it](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: i tried with giving like that. but still i am not getting the proper output :'(

Comment: the path shown is relative to the css file.  if your image and css aren't in the same folder use the full url for the image instead.

Comment: Wow...Thanks a lot :) now its coming dude :) initially i have pasted the image in someother folder.but now i put it in the same CSS folder.finally thank u very very very much :) it helped me :)